# jQuery tabs- content in non active tab spanning entire page creating white space below footer

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am using the following code to create a tabbed box. There is one tab with a lot of content and when that tab is not active, there is a ton of white space below footer. Essentially, the content isn't really hiding when it's not active, which I need it to do. I've included the base code along with the js script.

I tried setting the height and overflow to scroll, but not really happy with that. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's the skeleton code for reference:

```
<div class="product-collateral">
    <ul class="tabset">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab5">Tab 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab6">Tab 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab7">Tab 7</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="box-collateral tab-content">

        <div id="tab1">                          
        </div>

        <div id="tab2">
        </div>

        <div id="tab3">
        </div>

        <div id="tab4">
        </div>

        <div id="tab5">
        </div>

        <div id="tab6">
        </div>

        <div id="tab7">
        </div>

    </div><!-- /box-collateral tab-content -->
</div><!-- /product-collateral -->
```

And here's the js script

```
/*
 * jQuery Tabs plugin
 */
;(function($){
    $.fn.contentTabs = function(o){
        // default options
        var options = $.extend({
            activeClass:'active',
            addToParent:false,
            autoHeight:false,
            autoRotate:false,
            checkHash:false,
            animSpeed:400,
            switchTime:3000,
            effect: 'none', // "fade", "slide"
            tabLinks:'a',
            attrib:'href',
            event:'click'
        },o);

        return this.each(function(){
            var tabset = $(this), tabs = $();
            var tabLinks = tabset.find(options.tabLinks);
            var tabLinksParents = tabLinks.parent();
            var prevActiveLink = tabLinks.eq(0), currentTab, animating;
            var tabHolder;

            // handle location hash
            if(options.checkHash && tabLinks.filter('[' + options.attrib + '="' + location.hash + '"]').length) {
                (options.addToParent ? tabLinksParents : tabLinks).removeClass(options.activeClass);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    window.scrollTo(0,0);
                },1);
            }

            // init tabLinks
            tabLinks.each(function(){
                var link = $(this);
                var href = link.attr(options.attrib);
                var parent = link.parent();
                href = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('#'));

                // get elements
                var tab = $(href);
                tabs = tabs.add(tab);
                link.data('cparent', parent);
                link.data('ctab', tab);

                // find tab holder
                if(!tabHolder && tab.length) {
                    tabHolder = tab.parent();
                }

                // show only active tab
                var classOwner = options.addToParent ? parent : link;
                if(classOwner.hasClass(options.activeClass) || (options.checkHash && location.hash === href)) {
                    classOwner.addClass(options.activeClass);
                    prevActiveLink = link; currentTab = tab;
                    tab.removeClass(tabHiddenClass).width('');
                    contentTabsEffect[options.effect].show({tab:tab, fast:true});
                } else {
                    var tabWidth = tab.width();
                    if(tabWidth) {
                        tab.width(tabWidth);
                    }
                    tab.addClass(tabHiddenClass);
                }

                // event handler
                link.bind(options.event, function(e){
                    if(link != prevActiveLink && !animating) {
                        switchTab(prevActiveLink, link);
                        prevActiveLink = link;
                    }
                });
                if(options.attrib === 'href') {
                    link.bind('click', function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                }
            });

            // tab switch function
            function switchTab(oldLink, newLink) {
                animating = true;
                var oldTab = oldLink.data('ctab');
                var newTab = newLink.data('ctab');
                prevActiveLink = newLink;
                currentTab = newTab;

                // refresh pagination links
                (options.addToParent ? tabLinksParents : tabLinks).removeClass(options.activeClass);
                (options.addToParent ? newLink.data('cparent') : newLink).addClass(options.activeClass);

                // hide old tab
                resizeHolder(oldTab, true);
                contentTabsEffect[options.effect].hide({
                    speed: options.animSpeed,
                    tab:oldTab,
                    complete: function() {
                        // show current tab
                        resizeHolder(newTab.removeClass(tabHiddenClass).width(''));
                        contentTabsEffect[options.effect].show({
                            speed: options.animSpeed,
                            tab:newTab,
                            complete: function() {
                                if(!oldTab.is(newTab)) {
                                    oldTab.width(oldTab.width()).addClass(tabHiddenClass);
                                }
                                animating = false;
                                resizeHolder(newTab, false);
                                autoRotate();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

            // holder auto height
            function resizeHolder(block, state) {
                var curBlock = block && block.length ? block : currentTab;
                if(options.autoHeight && curBlock) {
                    tabHolder.stop();
                    if(state === false) {
                        tabHolder.css({height:''});
                    } else {
                        var origStyles = curBlock.attr('style');
                        curBlock.show().css({width:curBlock.width()});
                        var tabHeight = curBlock.outerHeight(true);
                        if(!origStyles) curBlock.removeAttr('style'); else curBlock.attr('style', origStyles);
                        if(state === true) {
                            tabHolder.css({height: tabHeight});
                        } else {
                            tabHolder.animate({height: tabHeight}, {duration: options.animSpeed});
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(options.autoHeight) {
                $(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function(){
                    tabs.not(currentTab).removeClass(tabHiddenClass).show().each(function(){
                        var tab = jQuery(this), tabWidth = tab.css({width:''}).width();
                        if(tabWidth) {
                            tab.width(tabWidth);
                        }
                    }).hide().addClass(tabHiddenClass);

                    resizeHolder(currentTab, false);
                });
            }

            // autorotation handling
            var rotationTimer;
            function nextTab() {
                var activeItem = (options.addToParent ? tabLinksParents : tabLinks).filter('.' + options.activeClass);
                var activeIndex = (options.addToParent ? tabLinksParents : tabLinks).index(activeItem);
                var newLink = tabLinks.eq(activeIndex < tabLinks.length - 1 ? activeIndex + 1 : 0);
                prevActiveLink = tabLinks.eq(activeIndex);
                switchTab(prevActiveLink, newLink);
            }
            function autoRotate() {
                if(options.autoRotate && tabLinks.length > 1) {
                    clearTimeout(rotationTimer);
                    rotationTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                        if(!animating) {
                            nextTab();
                        } else {
                            autoRotate();
                        }
                    }, options.switchTime);
                }
            }
            autoRotate();
        });
    };

    // add stylesheet for tabs on DOMReady
    var tabHiddenClass = 'js-tab-hidden';
    $(function() {
        var tabStyleSheet = $('<style type="text/css">')[0];
        var tabStyleRule = '.'+tabHiddenClass;
        tabStyleRule += '{position:absolute !important;left:-9999px !important;top:-9999px !important;display:block !important}';
        if (tabStyleSheet.styleSheet) {
            tabStyleSheet.styleSheet.cssText = tabStyleRule;
        } else {
            tabStyleSheet.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tabStyleRule));
        }
        $('head').append(tabStyleSheet);
    });

    // tab switch effects
    var contentTabsEffect = {
        none: {
            show: function(o) {
                o.tab.css({display:'block'});
                if(o.complete) o.complete();
            },
            hide: function(o) {
                o.tab.css({display:'none'});
                if(o.complete) o.complete();
            }
        },
        fade: {
            show: function(o) {
                if(o.fast) o.speed = 1;
                o.tab.fadeIn(o.speed);
                if(o.complete) setTimeout(o.complete, o.speed);
            },
            hide: function(o) {
                if(o.fast) o.speed = 1;
                o.tab.fadeOut(o.speed);
                if(o.complete) setTimeout(o.complete, o.speed);
            }
        },
        slide: {
            show: function(o) {
                var tabHeight = o.tab.show().css({width:o.tab.width()}).outerHeight(true);
                var tmpWrap = $('<div class="effect-div">').insertBefore(o.tab).append(o.tab);
                tmpWrap.css({width:'100%', overflow:'hidden', position:'relative'}); o.tab.css({marginTop:-tabHeight,display:'block'});
                if(o.fast) o.speed = 1;
                o.tab.animate({marginTop: 0}, {duration: o.speed, complete: function(){
                    o.tab.css({marginTop: '', width: ''}).insertBefore(tmpWrap);
                    tmpWrap.remove();
                    if(o.complete) o.complete();
                }});
            },
            hide: function(o) {
                var tabHeight = o.tab.show().css({width:o.tab.width()}).outerHeight(true);
                var tmpWrap = $('<div class="effect-div">').insertBefore(o.tab).append(o.tab);
                tmpWrap.css({width:'100%', overflow:'hidden', position:'relative'});

                if(o.fast) o.speed = 1;
                o.tab.animate({marginTop: -tabHeight}, {duration: o.speed, complete: function(){
                    o.tab.css({display:'none', marginTop:'', width:''}).insertBefore(tmpWrap);
                    tmpWrap.remove();
                    if(o.complete) o.complete();
                }});
            }
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved issue by changing value of `display:block;` to `display:none;` in this line of the js script:

```
tabStyleRule += '{position:absolute !important;left:-9999px !important;top:-9999px !important;display:block !important}';
```

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to figure out your code by interpretation, I believe it's best to hide all tab panels by default.

```
.ui-tabs-panel {
    display: none;
    /*overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;*/
}
```

Your `options.activeClass` should have:

```
.ui-tabs-panel.active {
    display: block;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /*transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;*/
}
```

This way you override the visible state by your `.active` class.
However, if it's animation you want to achieve, you might want to try with `opacity`. Not tested, and I usually fail these first attempts in CSS3 so in jQuery:

```
var tabPanelOptions = options.tabPanelOptions || {
    duration: 200,
    easing: 'linear'
};

$(options.tabPanel).fadeToggle(tabPanelOptions);
```

The whole idea is to switch/reverse visibility on the default state.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Tim...was able to take some elements from your answer and find a solution. I posted answer. Thanks again!